# What am I doing wrong in this select statement? I'm using oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am providing SQL that prompts the user for the name of a table. This SQL will provide a report of column names, data types, data lengths, data precision and indicate whether nulls are allowed for the specific table.

Here is the query I am running:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name
FROM employees
GROUP BY employee_id;

select department_id where employee_id = :table_name;


set echo

(select column_name, data_type, data_length,
data_precision, data_scale, nullable
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'employees'
order by column_name);
```

I get a window where a user is supposed to enter the table name but the second select statement fails to run.  It comes up with `ORA-00933: sql command not properly ended`.
If I run the second select statement separately I am getting a `no data found` message.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first two queries?

Answer (score 1):

First, You're missing the table name in this query:

```
select department_id where employee_id = :table_name;
```

It's should be:

```
select department_id from employees where employee_id = :table_name;
```

Second

```
set echo
```

Will give you an error:

> SP2-0265: echo must be set ON or OFF

You must add `ON` or `OFF` parameter for that command.
For example :

```
set echo ON;
```

More: [set echo](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/echo.html)

Third:

```
select column_name, data_type, data_length,
data_precision, data_scale, nullable
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'employees'
order by column_name
```

Maybe the comparison in where clause is case sensitive.

Try this:

```
select column_name, data_type, data_length,
data_precision, data_scale, nullable
from all_tab_columns
where lower(table_name) = 'employees'
order by column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `select department_id where employee_id = :table_name;`

is wrong.

The table is to be specified in the `from` clause.

Thanks